# InboundChannelAdapter issue with having fixedDelay and maxMessagesPerPoll - fixedDelay ignored

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using InboundChannelAdapter to fetch data from a database every 100000 miliseconds.

```
 @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inboundChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay="100000",maxMessagesPerPoll = "10000"))
```

Following by a transformer where I transform the fetched data into a json .

```
 @Transformer(inputChannel = "inboundChannel" , outputChannel = "outChannel")
 public Message<String> transformer(Message<List<MyOb>> items)
```

When I run the code, looks like `fixedDelay` is totally ignored (doesnt wait 100000 milis ) if `maxMessagesPerPoll` defined!

if I remove `maxMessagesPerPoll` it works.

In table i have only 2 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is some misunderstanding with that `maxMessagesPerPoll`. It indeed has meaning for a single poll cycle . By default it is really `1`, so, that’s how you see a delay for your two messages polled in two different cycles. Since you h  m have much more than 2 for that property, it is not a surprise that you don’t see a delay .